# Mostrar resultado ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Buenas a todos tengo la siguiente duda.
Estoy dando los primeros pasos con javascript y estoy haciendo una consulta mediante ajax y tengo el siguiente problema con el código.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','#organica',function(){
        var org = $(this).val();
        var div=$(this).parent();
        var op=" ";

        $.ajax({
            type:'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            url:'{!! URL::to('findPrograma')!!}',
            data: {'organica':org},
            success:function(data){

                //  no funciona
            op+='<option value="0" selected disabled>chose product</option>';
                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                op+='<option value="'+data[i].programa+'">'+data[i].programa+'</option>';
                    };

            div.find('#programa').append(op);

                                //  funciona
            $('#programa').append('<option>--Seleccionar--</option>');
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            $('#programa').append('<option value="'+data[i].programa+'">'+data[i].programa+'</option>');
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema ? ¿Algún mensaje de error?

Comment: ¿Verificaste que realizando la búsqueda lo encuentre `div.find('#programa')`?

Comment: El problema es que he puesto dos formas para mostrar los datos, pero la primera forma no funciona, console.log me muestra los datos pero no crea el <option>

Comment: Toma en consideración el comentario de Davilio , ese es tu error . no selecciona correctamente el elemento. ¿Y si solo hace `$('#programa').append(op);` ?

Comment: Tenéis razón, muchas gracias, ahora me funciona perfectamente, ya que la otra opción que tenia al modificar un valor del select no refrescaba los hijos y se amontonaban los valores

Comment: @PetaP3t4d0rZeta añadí mi comentario como respuesta, aunque si desea eliminar la pregunta también sería válido. Saludos

Comment: Este sitio no funciona como los foros. Por eso el `RESUELTO` en el título de la pregunta, sobra. Aquí el estado `RESUELTO` se indica de otra manera: **marcando como aceptada la respuesta que ha resuelto el problema. Eso se hace activando el checkmark ✓ a  la izquierda de la respuesta**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí en su `HTML` ,tiene un `ID` no sería necesario buscar este elemento con [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ya que los `ID` deben ser **únicos** , entonces solo  sería necesario acceder directamente a este elemento.

```
div.find('#programa').append(op); //No

$('#programa').append(op); //Sí
```